# SQL Constraint conditional Check: if column0 is null, column1 is not null and vice versa

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, check-constraints

I have this question around SQL constraints, in order to achieve following behavior:

TableA has two columns
column0 and column1, which only one can be NULL on data entry:
e.g.:
if column0 is null, column1 can't be null
if column1 is null, column0 can't be null

To achieve this, I've build following SQL constraints:

```
CONSTRAINT column01_not_null_chk
CHECK (
  ( column0 IS NOT NULL
  AND column1 IS NULL )
OR
  ( column1 IS NOT NULL
  AND column0 IS NULL ) )
```

is this correct to achieve my behavior? Because all SQL are rejected because of this constraint

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: This do not only check to not have two nulls, this force to have one and only one null.

Comment: @marc_s using postgresql sorry

Comment: @iguypouf this is meant to be. Only one of them (column0 or column1) must be not null

Comment: Look at the Zak's answer, he said same as I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you described means that at least one of them has to have value. So your constraint should be corrected to:

```
CONSTRAINT column01_not_null_chk
CHECK (column0 IS NOT NULL OR column1 IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Good catch! The question didn't say that two non `null` values should fail.

Comment: @Zack what a dumb I am! I should have simplify my logic, through this way. Is better for reading! Thx

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine on SQL Server:

```
create table t (
     column0 int null
   , column1 int null
, CONSTRAINT column01_not_null_chk
CHECK (
  ( column0 IS NOT NULL
  AND column1 IS NULL )
OR
  ( column1 IS NOT NULL
  AND column0 IS NULL ) )
);

insert into t values (null,1),(1,null);

select * from t;
--insert into t values (null,null) /* fail */
--insert into t values (1,1) /* fail */
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/OQZNE39497

returns:

```
+---------+---------+
| column0 | column1 |
+---------+---------+
| NULL    | 1       |
| 1       | NULL    |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning rextester tool @SqlZim, I was having other problem resulting in failure